# Can't figure out Has_many in select form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many

I'm trying to create a simple has_many relationship and then updating with forms.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Models

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  #position attributes
  has_many :educations, :foreign_key => "position_id"


class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :position 

  EDUCATION_CHOICES = ([["Undergrad", "0"],["Master", 1],["PHD", 2]])
```

Education data model has PK (auto), position_id, education_value, and timestamps.
education_value is meant to store the value from EDUCATION_CHOICES

```
startupfeeder_dev=# select * from educations;
 id | position_id | education_value |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  3 |          11 | 1               | 2012-04-27 08:26:28.077517 | 2012-04-27 16:27:50.330082
  1 |          12 | 1               | 2012-04-27 00:40:22.868336 | 2012-04-27 16:30:07.123653
  2 |          12 | 2               | 2012-04-27 00:45:06.613306 | 2012-04-27 16:30:07.127601
(3 rows)
```

Form:

```
    <%= f.select(:education_ids, Education::EDUCATION_CHOICES,{ :prompt => "Please select"},
    { :multiple => true, :size => 5 }) %>
```

Position Controller:

```
@position = Position.new(params[:position])
```

Standard, nothing added yet.

I've manually added some data and it pulls fine.

But update and create aren't mapping correctly.

This is what I get in my log:

```
Processing by PositionsController#create as HTML
```

Parameters: {"position"=>{"title"=>"test13", "education_ids"=>["", "1", "2"], "description"=>"test13"}, "commit"=>"Create Position", "authenticity_token"=>"XZRsnWTKkpprCOfmekOuXdPFKbZea1bfckCsLgG3/go=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223"}
  Education Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "educations".* FROM "educations" WHERE "educations"."id" IN (1, 2)

I think my problem is in the f.select where I have :education_ids, it should map to education_values.

Comment: edited form code to include mutli-select

Answer (score 0):

I can not see a particular error. It should not be necessary to define a foreign_key with `:foreign_key => "position_id"`, but it does not hurt. I just wonder how you can have multiple IDs in your log (`"education_ids"=>["", "1", "2"]`) if you have only one selectbox in your form? You may want to check out the railscasts about [updating through checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes) if you want to assign multiple "educations" for one "position". The guide about [rails form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) may offer some valuable hints, too. The first id passed in the array `["", "1", "2"]` is empty, it is possible that this could cause problems.

Comment: you're right. I added the multi option to the code recently and didn't update the pasted code.